# How to grey out non working day in agendaDay view with arshaw fullcalendar v2.3.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I am using the latest version of arshaw fullcalendar (version 2.3.0) and have a scenario where a calendar needs to show active working days and hours.

Ive done this using:

```
 businessHours:
 {
    start: '08:00',
    end: '17:00',
    dow: [2,3,4,5,6,0] // Monday is not a working day
 },
```

In agendaWeek view, it clearly shows the working days with the non working days 'greyed out'. In my case, Monday

[image]

But when I go to agendaDay view, Monday, which is not defined as a working day shows no greyed out sections and the entire day is white, making it look like a working day.

[image]

Shouldn't the entire day in agendaDay view be greyed out if the day is not specified to be a working day?

ref: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/businessHours/

Comment: It looks like this is a bug. [Reporting a bug for FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Reporting-Bugs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug but I created a workaround. It creates a background event when fullcalendar is in the agendaDay view and the current day is not in the DateOfWeek array.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    businessHours: {
        start: '08:00',
        end: '17:00',
        dow: [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    },

    viewRender: function (view, e) {
        var bh = view.options.businessHours,
            startDate = view.start;

        if (view.type === "agendaDay" && bh.dow.indexOf(startDate.day()) === -1) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                start: moment(startDate),
                end: moment(view.end),
                rendering: 'background',
                className: 'fc-nonbusiness'
            }, false);

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                start: moment(startDate),
                allDay: true,
                rendering: 'background',
                className: 'fc-nonbusiness'
            }, false);
        }
    }
});
```

There are a few things that can be improved:

- The selector `$('#calendar')` can be something generic.
- When you access the day multiple times, `.fullCalendar('renderEvent',` will append multiple background events.

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2etu70g6/)

Comment: Thank you so much! This works great!

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                                                                    start: moment(startDate).hour(0).minute(0),
                                                                    end: moment(view.end),
                                                                    rendering: 'background',
                                                                    className: 'fc-nonbusiness'
                                                                }, true);

Comment: @MarkRaa Thanks. The only thing left is built a check to see if there are already background events for the current day.

Comment: yes. However, my current implementation doesn't use other background events so using it exclusively to grey out the day is fine for now. 

Again, thank you so much! :)